# seek in audio file based on time

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, core-audio

Seeking through an audio file based on the packet level is simple. One just has to change *currentPacket* when filling the next buffer:

```
AudioFileReadPackets(_audioFile, false, &numBytes, _packetDescs, _currentPacket, &numPackets, buffer->mAudioData);
```

But what if you want to seek to position 10s from the beginning of the file?
For the CBR files this should be simple to calculate - but what about VBR files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the ExtAudio* API. One can convert the input files to LPCM on the fly and then seeking becomes trivial.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without converting the entire file into LPCM?